# Heroku timeout while getting data from external resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout, delayed-job

I am new to Heroku I have an application which sends request to an external resource and get response this response can take more than 30 seconds may be 1 to 3 minutes. And I got error H-12 I can not use delay_job because my next step is totally dependent on the data of external resource. Please any one can help me what should I do to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building upon @johns answer, heroku's cedar stack provides more options other than it's default `web`.

You'll want to use delayed_job or my personal favourite [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) to run your jobs.

Start by creating a file called `Procfile` in the root directory of your project

```
web:    bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 15
```

Documentation for the Procfile is available on [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

Add sidekiq to your gemfile and run `bundle install`

You'll need a redis server running like [redistogo](https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo) and you should install redis on your development environment too.

Now create a `workers` directory in your `app` directory and create a worker class like so:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    # insert slow task here
  end
end
```

When you want to perform the slow task call, say in your controller call

```
MyWorker.perform_async()
```

It can take arguments too like so

```
def perform(name)
   MyModel.doSomethingSlow(name)
end
```

and then

```
MyWorker.perform_async("foobar")
```

Keep in mind this is asynchronous, the method will run in the background and unless you have something in your code to check the result is finished you won't know.

So see this all in action on development, make sure you have foreman installed (installed by default with the heroku toolbelt) and call `foreman start`

This will start both your web and worker on your local machine.

To get this running on heroku you just need to scale up the worker. The heroku console will give you an option to do this or you can use the command line `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Comment: thanks for reply I follow [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) i have worker class and an perform method which takes two arguments i call the perform method with MyWorker.perform_async(arg1,arg2) but I am getting error wrong no of agrgument (2 for 1)

Comment: actually I am passing a session variable in second argument.

Comment: Is the second argument included in your perform definition? def perform(arg1, arg2)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the values of the arguments you send though will be stored in and serialized in redis. This means that if you pass a model into perform it's going to store the whole thing. A better practice is to pass an id and let the perform method look it up

Comment: MyWorker.perform_async(arg1,session.to_yaml) and in worker YAML.load session did trick for me

Comment: Great to hear. Could you mark my answer as accepted so that others with the same problem can find it?

Comment: can you please help me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323798/delayed-job-mongoid-is-not-writing-data-in-backend)

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to speed up the retrieval of your external data. The maximum time a web request has to respond is 30 seconds before it is killed by heroku and an h12 returned.

1-2 minute requests are simply not possible on Heroku. You only option would be to cache the data if possible after retrieving it periodically. Alternatively, a delayed_job style approach but you then poll the job until it completes via Ajax and when the data is available at the server prompt the user to continue.