# delayed_job_mongoid is not writing data in backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, mongoid3

I have mongoid model

```
class RequestResponse
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :body, type: String
  field :job_id, type: Fixnum
  field :completed, type: Boolean
end
```

and according to rails cast I have a class in my lib folder

```
class MyJob < Struct.new(:session, :url, :r_id)
  def perform
    rr = RequestResponse.find(r_id)
    session = YAML.load session
    rr.body = session.get(url).body
    rr.completed = true
    rr.save
  end
end
```

I called some where in my controller

```
rr = RequestResponse.new
rr.save
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MyJob.new(session.to_yaml, url, rr.id),3)
```

I can see with

```
rake jobs:work
1 jobs processed at 19.3392 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

And the result is not stored in the table for rr if i check

```
rr.body
```

it is still nill any one can help me out Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Struct.new creates instances variable for you that you can access using either `self` or `@`

Try this

```
class MyJob < Struct.new(:session, :url, :r_id)
  def perform
    rr = RequestResponse.find(@r_id)
    session = YAML.load @session
    rr.body = session.get(@url).body
    rr.completed = true
    rr.save
  end
end
```

Comment: can you try to do `puts @session.inspect` in your job and see what it prints out ?

Answer (score 0):

My job was silently deleted. I have fixed the problem by creating a file in config/initializers/custom.rb and put this line

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../../lib/my_job"))
```